# No host specified in URI $uri in imagenewtwork

Tags: flutter, dart

So I have a problem with image network so i have a class model that is associated with firebase and i call those items from firebase in artist provider, however i checked the url of the image is formatted correctly even i tried to set it like this : `Image.network("https://example.com")` it dispaly the image successfully but when i set it like this : 
`artistConsumer.items[index].artistImage,` it shows an exception says that : 
No host specified in URI 
this is the class model :

```
import 'dart:convert';

class ArtistModel {
  String artistImage;
  String artistName;
  String catagoryAr;
  String catagoryEn;

  ArtistModel({
    required this.artistImage,
    required this.artistName,
    required this.catagoryAr,
    required this.catagoryEn,
  });

  factory ArtistModel.fromRawJson(String str) =>
      ArtistModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

  String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

  factory ArtistModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ArtistModel(
        artistImage: json["artistImage"] ?? '',
        artistName: json["artistName"] ?? '',
        catagoryAr: json["catagoryAr"] ?? '',
        catagoryEn: json["catagoryEN"] ?? '',
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "artistImage": artistImage,
        "artistName": artistName,
        "catagoryAr": catagoryAr,
        "catagoryEN": catagoryEn,
      };
}
```

and this is the provier : 
```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import '../models/artist_model.dart';

class ArtistProvider with ChangeNotifier {
bool isFav = false;
bool isFailed = false;
bool isLoading = false;

List items = [];
List get item => items;

Future loadArtistFromFirestore() async {
isLoading = true;

```
isFailed = false;
final cartItemsRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('artwork');
final cartItemsSnapshot = await cartItemsRef.get();
final cartItemsData = cartItemsSnapshot.docs;
final List<ArtistModel> loadedCartItems = [];
for (var doc in cartItemsData) {
  loadedCartItems.add(ArtistModel.fromJson(doc.data()));
}
items = loadedCartItems;

isLoading = false;
isFailed = true;
notifyListeners();

if (kDebugMode) {
  print('Loaded ${items.length} artwork items from Firestore');
}
```

}
}

```
<br/>
and this is how to call it in UI : <br/>
```

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'package:shaghaf/screens/sub_screens/profile_artist_details_screen.dart';
import '../../providers/artists_provider.dart';
import '../../widgets/static_widget/common_artist_card.dart';
import '../../widgets/static_widget/coustom_appbar_widget.dart';

class CommonArtistScreen extends StatefulWidget {
const CommonArtistScreen({super.key});

@override
State createState() => _CommonArtistScreenState();
}

class _CommonArtistScreenState extends State {
// @override
// void initState() {
//   Provider.of(context, listen: false)
//       .loadArtistFromFirestore();
//   super.initState();
// }
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
Provider.of(context, listen: false)
.loadArtistFromFirestore();
});
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//MediaQuery for more responsive UI
Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Consumer<ArtistProvider>(builder: (context, artistConsumer, _) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
          child: CostuomAppBar(
            menueFunction: () {},
            iconBehavior: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            isDetails: false,
            isHome: false,
            profileName: '',
            title: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.homescreencommonartits,
            isOtherScreens: false,
            iconData: const Icon(
              Icons.arrow_back,
            ),
            subTitle: '',
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: size.width,
          child: Padding(
            padding:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24, vertical: 12),
            child: GridView.builder(
              itemCount: artistConsumer.items.length,
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (_) => ProfileArtistDetailsScreen(
                              artWorkImage:
                                  artistConsumer.items[index].artistImage,
                              artistName:
                                  artistConsumer.items[index].artistName,
                              workCatagory:
                                  artistConsumer.items[index].catagoryAr,
                            )));
                  },
                  child: CommonArtistCard(
                    artistName: artistConsumer.items[index].artistName,
                    catagory: artistConsumer.items[index].catagoryAr,
                    artistPic: artistConsumer.items[index].artistImage,
                  ),
                );
              },
              gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                mainAxisSpacing: 16.0,
                crossAxisSpacing: 16.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ));
  }),
);
```

}
}

```
<br/>
so as I had told i try to change the url it didn't work even when i try the to call the image itself it did displayed so that means the url is formatted in good way!
```